# numpy cumulative product: normalizing result after each prod operation along axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, normalization

I have an array, for example (2,1000) shape. i need to get a cumulative product along axis=1, thats not a problem, though if my numbers are below 1 - they quickly get to zero, if they are above 1 - they quickly get to Inf. The question is if there any way to normalize every column along axis=0 (i.e. by sum) after every product operation, without cycles?

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 10, (2,1000)).astype('float')
p = np.cumprod(a, axis=1)
print p[:,-1]
```

this gives me
    [ inf  inf]

```
a = np.random.random((2,1000))
p = np.cumprod(a, axis=1)
print p[:,-1]
```

this gives me
    [ 0.  0.]

and i want something like
    [0.5, 0.5]

This works like partial solution now:

```
vars = 100
a = np.random.random((vars, 1000))
p = np.ones((vars, 1))
step_window = 100
step = int(a.shape[1]/step_window)
for i in range(step):
    temp = np.cumprod(a[:, i*step_window:(i+1)*step_window], axis=1) 
    temp[:,-1] /= temp[:,-1].sum() 
    p *= temp[:,-1].reshape((vars, 1)) 
    p /= p.sum() '
```

Comment: You should add your partial solution to the question, rather than leaving it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure I have understood you algorithm very well, but lets say your array is:

```
[[a c e g]
 [b d f h]]
```

If I get you right, you will first compute `a*c` and `b*d`, and before multiplying by `e` and `f`, you would divide both numbers by `a*c + b*d`, and get `a*c / (a*c + b*d)` and `b*d / (a*c + b*d)`. When you multiply by `e` and `f`, your new normalizing factor is `(a*c*e + b*d*f) / (a*c + b*d)`, and the resulting values before the next multiplication are `a*c*e / (a*c*e + b*d*f)` and `b*d*f / (a*c*e + b*d*f)`. You probably see the pattern arising...

If you divide those expression by the numerator, you get `1 / (1 + a*c*e/b/d/f)` and `1 / (1 + b*d*f/a/c/e)`, so you can get your results computing the products of the ratios of your two rows:

```
a = np.random.random((2, 1000))
temp = np.cumprod(a[1] / a[0])
p = 1 / (1 + np.vstack((temp, 1/temp)))
```

Your expectation of the result being `[0.5, 0.5]` doesn't seem to be true, though, as it seems to quickly oscillate between being `[0, 1]` and `[1, 0]`.

[image]

Comment: That works with 0'th axis.shape = 2, though with bigger shape it seems does not, though you get my point exactly, thank you.
as for [0.5 0.5] expectation i think the pure random numbers generator (not pseudo) would do this.. maybe i am wrong though. anyways i dont have random numbers there in my original task :)

Comment: If you have more than two items in the 0-th axis, you can produce a similar result, but it will involve more ratios of items, e.g. for a three item 0-th axis you would do something like `t10 = np.cumprod(a[1] / a[0]); t20 = np.cumprod(a[1] / a[0]); t21 = np.cumprod(a[2] / a[1]); p = np.vstack((1/(1+t10+t20), 1/(1+1/t10+t21), 1/(1+1/t20+1/t21)))`. As for the expectation value, I think that without floating point errors, you will get a continuously oscillating result. The average of all values will probably converge to 0.5, but the actual values won't.

Comment: with my case of around 100 rows that would be too much typing :)
and im not familiar with fundamental FP errors, so i prefer to agree with you on this case